# subprocess call unable to find dot although it's installed

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda, spyder

I'm following this [this sample code](https://gist.github.com/WillKoehrsen/ff77f5f308362819805a3defd9495ffd) provided by [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-visualize-a-decision-tree-from-a-random-forest-in-python-using-scikit-learn-38ad2d75f21c). The IDE is Spyder 4.1.5 with Python 3.8, anaconda got the below exception saying "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified".

I'm new to python (and Spyder), so not sure what file was missing as the exception message didn't include a filename. Any hint will be highly appreciated.

I've checked the environment, `dot` is available in path, and package `graphviz` has been installed.

**Exception trace:**

```
runfile('C:/my/work/smlb/challenge_1/code/tree_to_image.py', wdir='C:/my/work/smlb/challenge_1/code')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\my\work\smlb\challenge_1\code\tree_to_image.py", line 31, in <module>
    call(['dot', '-Tpng', 'tree.dot', '-o', 'tree.png', '-Gdpi=600'])

  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 340, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:

  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 105, in __init__
    super(SubprocessPopen, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,

  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

**The sample code I was trying to run:**

I'm trying to run the below sample source code to generate an image to visualize a binary decision.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()

# Model (can also use single decision tree)
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10)

# Train
model.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
# Extract single tree
estimator = model.estimators_[5]

from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
# Export as dot file
export_graphviz(estimator, out_file='tree.dot', 
                feature_names = iris.feature_names,
                class_names = iris.target_names,
                rounded = True, proportion = False, 
                precision = 2, filled = True)

# Convert to png using system command (requires Graphviz)
from subprocess import call
call(['dot', '-Tpng', 'tree.dot', '-o', 'tree.png', '-Gdpi=600'])
#
# It works if directly call command `dot -Tpng tree.dot -o tree.png -Gdpi=600`
# but the subprocess call here doesn't work
#

# Display in jupyter notebook
from IPython.display import Image
Image(filename = 'tree.png')
```

**Check python packages in Anaconda Prompt:**

```
(base) C:\Users\user>conda list graphviz
# packages in environment at C:\Users\user\anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
graphviz                  2.38                 hfd603c8_2
python-graphviz           0.16               pyhd3eb1b0_1

(base) C:\Users\user>where dot
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Library\bin\dot.bat

(base) C:\Users\user>
```

Comment: does it convert tree.dot to tree.png?

Comment: Yes. the file `tree.dot` has been generated; the error happens at a later step trying to convert it to .png.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, the error is at the line

```
call(['dot', '-Tpng', 'tree.dot', '-o', 'tree.png', '-Gdpi=600'])
```

and comes down to

```
hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
```

in the `subprocess` module. So it seems that the `executable`, i.e. `dot` cannot be found. Check if you can run `where dot` in a cmd. If not, then you probably need to install the [graphviz](https://graphviz.org/download/) library. Make sure to check "Add to path" during the installation

Comment: I've check the environment, `dot` is available in path, and package `graphviz` is installed already.

Comment: It works if directly call command `dot -Tpng tree.dot -o tree.png -Gdpi=600` in Anaconda Prompt; just the subprocess call doesn't work.